# Smarty общие templates и templates_c для всех вложенных каталогов

Tags: php, smarty

File /var/www/html/smarty/smarty/logs.php

```
require_once '../libs/SmartyBC.class.php';
class logs  extends SmartyBC {

   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();

        $workdir = "/var/www/html/smarty/smarty";
        $this->setTemplateDir("$workdir/templates/");
        $this->setCompileDir("$workdir/templates_c/");
        $this->setConfigDir("$workdir/configs/");
        $this->setCacheDir("$workdir/cache/");

        $this->caching = Smarty::CACHING_LIFETIME_CURRENT;
        $this->assign('app_name', 'Guest Book');
   }
}
```

File /var/www/html/smarty/smarty/SubFolder/index.php

```
define('SMARTY_RESOURCE_CHAR_SET', 'UTF-8');
//Подключаем класс смарти
require_once '../logs.php';
//Создадим обьект класса смарти
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
print_r($smarty->getTemplateDir()); // Array ( [0] => /var/www/html/smarty/smarty/SubFolder/templates/ )
$smarty->display('SubFolder/index.tpl');
```

Хочу структуру

```
workdir\
        -\templates\
        -\templates\SubFolder\index.tpl
        -\templates\SubFolder2\index.tpl
        -\templates_с\
        -\templates_с\SubFolder(Не обязательно)\
        -\templates_с\SubFolder2(Не обязательно)\
        -\SubFolder\index.php
        -\SubFolder2\index.php
```

Выходит

```
workdir\
        -\templates\
        -\templates_с\
        -\SubFolder\index.php
        -\SubFolder\templates\
        -\SubFolder\templates_с\
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: и где вы используете этот класс `logs` ? и зачем вам этот  `BC` сдался?

Comment: BC нужен для использования php в темплейтах

Comment: пишите бизнес-логику отдельно от шаблонов. Да и все равно в подавляющем большинстве случаев смарти позволяет и так вызывать все пхп функции, и все остальное. тэг `{php}` в принципе и не нужен

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему

```
$smarty = new SmartyBC();
```

Замел на

```
$smarty = new logs();
```

Видимо примелькалось, спасибо **teran**